# How to Consume iis hosted wcf service hosted in win server 16 that I can only access via VPN?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a windows server 2016 that I can only access through a VPN, 2 methods that only run while hosten on the server.

I also have a pc, we will call it pc1 that has all my development tools ND where i do all coding

1st I built a console app and tested that the parameters are correct. After that I put both methods into wcf service. Hosted it on the server successfully. Within the server I can access the service via

"http://servername:7777/servicename.svc".

Problem is now I can't access the services on my pc1, the idea is to create another set of wcf service that can be hosted over a public ip and consume the once hosted on the server, but I cannot get access, I do not know if it's a firewall issue or if there is a way to configure the VPN access so I can authenticate as u access.

Thanx for your quick response

Comment: In theory, as long as the network between the server and the client is smooth, we can call services on the client. There is no need to host the service through additional machines with public IP. So I suggest you visit the service page on the client browser to make sure the network is clear.

Comment: I belive that would work but when I browse the url it can't reach the server. Reason I need to connect to another sever is because the other server I have complete control, ND public ip because it will be consumed by mobile devices ND all requests will come from different sources